# Trying to remember card game I played a few years back

Tags: identify-this-game, phase-10

I still remember the rules pretty well, the name escapes me though. The cards look a lot like Phase 10, so I'm hoping my grandma didn't just make it up.

- Each player is dealt a hand of 6(?) cards
- Each player is also dealt a stack of 30 cards that is face down except for the top card which can be flipped
- And the remaining cards become the draw pile.
- The goal is to get rid of your whole stack of 30, by placing your cards on one of 4 spots around the draw pile.
- Each spot around the pile your trying to place cards in order of 1-12, once it reaches 12 the spot is restarted.
- You are forced to always place a card, and if no spot on either of the 4 piles is available, you have 4 rows by you that you can stack. You can take cards from it on your turn, but only in the order they're placed so you had to be careful.
- There were a couple of Free cards that you could place anywhere.

Even though it sounds complicated written out it was played pretty simply, and was a lot of fun. Hoping to find it again through some help on here, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Board and Card games. Great first question. Lots of details.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like [Skip-Bo or Spite and Malice](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1269/skip-bo):

> Each player is dealt a stockpile of 30 cards. The winner will be
> whoever manages to empty their stockpile first. Cards are played onto
> four shared building piles in numerical sequence from 1 to 12. On each
> turn, a player draws until they have five cards in their hand, and
> then plays cards from: their hand, a top card of their discard piles,
> or their stockpile. At the end of their turn, a player must discard
> onto one of their four personal discard piles. Strategy involves the
> organizing of cards into the discard piles, care in not setting up the
> next players for good plays, knowing when to play from which option,
> and especially the timing of playing a valuable "Skip-bo" wildcard.
>
> Skip-bo is based on Traditional Card Games: Spite and Malice.

Comment: Yeah, OP has pro verbatim spat out Skip-Bo's rulebook. Quite amazing, honestly.